# Restrict IONIC side menu from auto populating for large screens

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I have implemented side menu for my IONIC 5.0.0 application. In smaller device side menu is shrinking to Hamburger icon (working fine). I want the same behavior in large screens also  but unfortunately the menu is fully visible in the landscape mode of my iPad (6th gen). Does anyone know how to hide the menu in Hamburger icon always (for all device).

Comment: Open your `app.scss` and change screen size for menu.

Comment: @Najamussaqib I didn't understand it properly. Can you please explain in details.

Comment: Try `.split-pane-visible >.split-pane-side {
    min-width: 150px!important;
    max-width: 150px!important;
  }` in your global.scss

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems you need to use `when="false"` property in the `ion-split-pane` component. Please find `app.component.html`. The location should be like `src/app/app.component.html` and change the following line from

```
<ion-split-pane>
```

to

```
<ion-split-pane when="false">
```

To learn more about the `ion-split-pane` component, [visit this link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/split-pane).

Comment: It is worked. Thank you [Milan Chandro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3867422/milan-chandro)